# How to download Active Perl Zip for Windows Server 2003

Tags: perl, zip, activeperl

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question . But I'm trying to install Active Perl for IIS in windows 2003 server. I need to build a website in perl. So I want to follow the steps as given in this document 
    http://www.howtogeek.com/50500/how-to-install-perl-on-iis-6-for-windows-server-2003/

In the steps it is mentioned that download ActiveState Perl distribution package (get the AS zip file and not the installer) " .  But I'm unable to find the zip file in this site http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads . I can only see .msi .  Please help me in finding in this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveState has not produced the .zip version for windows in a while.  ActivePerl installs from .msi just fine & if it sees IIS is already installed, it will configure itself accordingly.  Of course if you strongly prefer a copy of Perl as outdated as the OS you'd like to install it onto, you can always pony up for a Business or Enterprise Edition subscription.

Word to the wise: Server 2003 is under extended support for only another 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ZIP file instead of the MSI installer, copy the MSI URL to the clipboard, change the extension from `.msi` to `.zip`, and then load the file. Today is June 23, 2014 and it has just worked fine for `ActivePerl-5.16.3.1604-MSWin32-x86-298023.zip`.

Comment: from the URL https://activeperl.software.informer.com/download/ I am able to download exe, but how to covert that into zip?